# adb command for listing all elements of current activity

Tags: android, xpath, command-line, adb

***Is there any adb command to list all elements of current activity on Andoird app?***
I mean ,can i use adb shell and listing all available element (IDs or hierarchy) of FocusedActivity?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
```

You will get a XML file here, an XML with the dump of current UI hierarchy

```
UI hierchary dumped to: /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

You can then download it by accessing it from Android Studio device explorer.

Comment: Thanks Sushobh Nadiger.